# Not able to bind json data to dynamically loaded child component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to dynamically load a child component from the parent component. From the parent component I need to pass some parameter to the child which would be used in the child component to make a service call and retrieve some data from WebAPI Service. the returned data should be bound to some input controls in the child component.

for testing purpose I have created a plunker wherein I am loading a child component from the parent and I am trying to bind the input controls data from the JSON object which i have initialized locally. I am facing some issues here, the data is not getting bound here properly.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xROfBv?p=preview) URL

my child component code

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';

const SAMPLE: Sample[] = [
    { queueId: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
    { queueId: 12, name: 'Narco' },
    { queueId: 19, name: 'Magma' },
    { queueId: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'load',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  template:`<h1>This is from loader</h1>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="resultData.queueId" />

  `
})
export class Loader{
    @Input() ParentID : any; 
   // resultData : any;
    resultData = SAMPLE;
    constructor()
    {


    }
}


export class Sample {
    queueId: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Comment: Isn't resultData is Sample[] and you template expecting it to be Sample. Change them late to [(ngModel)]="resultData[0].queueId"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't `resultData` is `Sample[]` and you template expecting it to be `Sample`.  Update the template such that you get `Sample` e.g.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="resultData[0].queue.Id />
```